# Getting parity symmetric distributions by summing two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, symmetry

Lets denote a random variable with a distribution $f$ to be parity symmetric if $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$ in the target space of the random variable.

Suppose X is a parity symmetric random variable and Y is another random variable mapping between the same spaces as X.

What are some general conditions known when $X + Y$ is parity symmetric?

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Do keep in mind that I am always thinking of continuous random variables.

Comment: $X$ has median and mean zero, because $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}$.



 $E[X+Y] = E[Y]$.

Comment: So $X$ is parity symmetric, and $X+Y$ is also parity symmetric, and your question is what can be said about $Y$?  Under mild assumptions one should be able to easily prove that $Y$ is also symmetric.

Comment: I am looking for cases when Y is not symmetric in your above setting

Comment: sorry, since you didnt "@antkam" i did not see your msg until now.  :)  anyway, the easiest way, and kinda "cheating", is to realize that two PDFs behave the same if they differ in only a finite (or countably infinite) number of points, because that doesn't affect the CDF at all.  so simply pick some $Y$ with symmetric $f_Y(y)$ and change one non-zero value e.g. add $1$ to $f_Y(1)$.  Would this count for your purpose?  If not, there should be a way to redefine "parity symmetric" to rule this out.